# Is modifying /etc/hostname enough to change the hostname?

Tags: linux, hosts, hostname

I was setting the hostname on my Linux machine with below steps:

1. `echo "ABCD" > /etc/hostname`
2. `hostname -F /etc/hostname`
3. Exit from terminal or reboot system
4. Now I can see the new hostname.

Now my question is: What I did here, is that enough for setting the hostname or do I additionally have to change other configuration files, if any?

Comment: Different distributions provide different ways. What distribution are you referring to? Linux is just the kernel...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything, since you've already changed the hostname by editing `/etc/hostname`. If you're trying to do something other than change the hostname as the host knows it, [please elaborate](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

[`/etc/hosts`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?hosts) just lists symbolic names for **IPs**, so that for example `ping localhost` does the same as `ping 127.0.0.1` if you have a line starting with `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` somewhere else on the line (whitespace separated). You can of course add `abcd` to that line, but that has nothing to do with the hostname in `/etc/hostname`, other than that they coincidentally are the same string. You *can't* for example enter <strike>`localhost abcd`</strike> in the file and expect that to resolve abcd → localhost → 127.0.0.1.

PS: [DNS names are not case sensitive](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4343.txt), but are conventionally written in lowercase.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, you need to change both /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts.

Comment: Ok then what changes i need to do in /etc/hosts file can you please tell me.

Comment: There is a map from hostname to 127.0.1.1

Comment: If you have a reference to the old host name in `/etc/hosts` and didn't change it, you wouldn't be able to resolve the new host name. Some server apps don't work if your host name does not resolve to an IP address

Comment: Ok thank you for explanation. My current hosts file display as "127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain           localhost". Now i need to add one new line "127.0.1.1       localhost.localdomain           abcd". RIGHT?

Comment: [You don't need to do this.](http://superuser.com/a/745911/2259)